# Keyboard shortcut to check-in current file in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there any Keyboard Shortcut available in Visual Studio 2010 to Check-In the current editing file in TFS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using vs 2012 and I have the option to create one:

Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard > *Type "CheckIn" in Show commands containing* > *click on* File.TfsCheckIn

Here I took <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> as shortcut and put "use new shortcut in: Global"

This works for me, think it might be the same in 2010